# Excel VBA dict like declaration, initialiazation and accessing

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to declare a dict with key values and access it. I'm using Excel VBA but I'm getting error (Excel 2010).

The structure I would like to declare is this (Python notation):

```py
ktable = {'a': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
          'b': [2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
          'c': [5.0, 0.0, 6.0],
          'd': [8.0, 0.0, 9.0],
          'e': [1.5, 0.5, 0.0],
          'f': [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]}
```

My code is this:

```vb
Public ktable As New Collection
Dim kt_a: kt_a = Array(1# , 2# , 3# )
Dim kt_b: kt_b = Array(2# , 3# , 4# )
Dim kt_c: kt_c = Array(5# , 0# , 6# )
Dim kt_d: kt_d = Array(8# , 0# , 9# )
Dim kt_e: kt_e = Array(1.5, 0.5, 0# )
Dim kt_f: kt_f = Array(0# , 0.5, 1# )
ktable.Add kt_a, "a"
ktable.Add kt_b, "b"
ktable.Add kt_c, "c"
ktable.Add kt_d, "d"
ktable.Add kt_e, "e"
ktable.Add kt_f, "f"

Sub test()
    Debug.Print ktable.Item("a")(1)
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? I get 'Runtime Error 424'.

EDIT:

Ok, so far been able to work with the code below, using info from both answers - specifically the comment about using Tools -> Reference was very helpful. Will wait some time and then

```vb
Option Explicit

Public ktable

Sub INIT_CONSTANTS()
    'ktable={'a' : [ 1.0 , 2.0  ,  3.0  ],
             'b' : [ 2.0 , 3.0  ,  4.0  ],
             'c' : [ 5.0,  0.0  ,  6.0  ],
             'd' : [ 8.0,  0.0  ,  9.0  ],
             'e' : [ 1.5,  0.5  ,  0.0  ],
             'f' : [ 0.0,  0.5  ,  1.0  ]}
    Set ktable = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If Not ktable.Exists("a") Then
        Dim kt_a: kt_a = Array(1# , 2# , 3# )
        Dim kt_b: kt_b = Array(2# , 3# , 4# )
        Dim kt_c: kt_c = Array(5# , 0# , 6# )
        Dim kt_d: kt_d = Array(8# , 0# , 9# )
        Dim kt_e: kt_e = Array(1.5, 0.5, 0# )
        Dim kt_f: kt_f = Array(0# , 0.5, 1# )
        ktable.Add "a", kt_a
        ktable.Add "b", kt_b
        ktable.Add "c", kt_c
        ktable.Add "d", kt_d
        ktable.Add "e", kt_e
        ktable.Add "f", kt_f
    End If
End Sub

Sub test()
INIT_CONSTANTS
    Debug.Print ktable.Item("a")(0)
End Sub
```

EDIT2:

Ok, shortest answer is below. Thanks @Rory for pointing I didn't need the intermediate variable.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public ktable

Sub INIT_CONSTANTS()
    Set ktable = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If Not ktable.Exists("a") Then
        ktable.Add "a", Array(1# , 2# , 3# )
        ktable.Add "b", Array(2# , 3# , 4# )
        ktable.Add "c", Array(5# , 0# , 6# )
        ktable.Add "d", Array(8# , 0# , 9# )
        ktable.Add "e", Array(1.5, 0.5, 0# )
        ktable.Add "f", Array(0# , 0.5, 1# )
    End If
End Sub

Sub test()
INIT_CONSTANTS
    Debug.Print ktable.Item("a")(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Collection` rather than a `Dictionary`?

Comment: This is a static element, there is no reason to change numbers/keys at runtime, I just need to be able to reference this easy and it must be accessible to all Functions on the Module. Edit: grammar

Comment: Generally, but not dogmatically, one should prefer a dictionary to a collection in VBA. For your use-case (as you presented it) the dictionary and collection both achieve the same result - and you should select the one that is most easiest to code and deploy (ceteris paribus). In cases where the developer has to worry about finding/acquiring references to make a dictionary work (and does not want to late-bind); the poorly designed, but intrinsically available VBA `Collection`, does find use. Please also consider accepting answers for this question - and previous questions you have asked.

Comment: @RusanKax Thanks. Liked the Latin phrase. I used things from both answers and comments to achieve the desired result, so I voted up everyone. There is no way to accept two answers, which is a problem - There is no way to tell SO to merge two answers AFAIK. I didn't accept any answers because had doubt on which... I had only one other question with no answers accepted so I went through my questions, found it and accepted one answer - One I hadn't seem before but was similar to what I ended up doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialise like this outside of a `Sub`. This works:

```
Public ktable As New Collection

Sub test()
    Dim kt_a: kt_a = Array(1#, 2#, 3#)
    Dim kt_b: kt_b = Array(2#, 3#, 4#)
    Dim kt_c: kt_c = Array(5#, 0#, 6#)
    Dim kt_d: kt_d = Array(8#, 0#, 9#)
    Dim kt_e: kt_e = Array(1.5, 0.5, 0#)
    Dim kt_f: kt_f = Array(0#, 0.5, 1#)
    ktable.Add kt_a, "a"
    ktable.Add kt_b, "b"
    ktable.Add kt_c, "c"
    ktable.Add kt_d, "d"
    ktable.Add kt_e, "e"
    ktable.Add kt_f, "f"
        Debug.Print ktable.Item("a")(1)
End Sub
```

Or more typically, use some form of "initialising" sub, like this:

```
Public ktable As New Collection

Sub INIT_thing(ByRef C As Collection)
    Dim kt_a: kt_a = Array(1, 2, 3)
    Dim kt_b: kt_b = Array(2, 3, 4)
    Dim kt_c: kt_c = Array(5#, 0#, 6#)
    Dim kt_d: kt_d = Array(8#, 0#, 9#)
    Dim kt_e: kt_e = Array(1.5, 0.5, 0#)
    Dim kt_f: kt_f = Array(0#, 0.5, 1#)
    C.Add kt_a, "a"
    C.Add kt_b, "b"
    C.Add kt_c, "c"
    C.Add kt_d, "d"
    C.Add kt_e, "e"
    C.Add kt_f, "f"

End Sub

Sub test()
   Call INIT_thing(ktable)
   Debug.Print ktable.Item("a")(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making some confusion.

```
Python list == VBA collection
Python dictionary == Microsoft Scripting dictionary
```

Dictionaries in VBA are used as follows:

**PREREQUISITES:** reference the `MS Scripting Runtime` into your Tools/References.

Then create the MS Scripting dictionary:

```
Set MSdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Hence add your values:

```
If Not MSdict.Exists(key) Then 
    MSdict.Add key, value
End If
```

Comment: VBA's Dictionary is just a `Microsoft.Scripting.Dictionary` VBA doesn't own it so saying VBA's Dictionary is a bit off :) Btw. If you add references to `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime` it's recommended to use the early-binding `Dim d as Dictionary` followed by `Set d = new Dictionary` - the advantage is speed and intelli-sense.

Comment: Is there a less boring way to initialize? I'm sensing 3*3*6+1 lines of code compared to the 6 lines in Python...

Comment: Re initialising: you don't need the variables for the arrays.

Comment: @Rory, the invitation is for everyone who feels an answer can be improved: don't hesitate to suggest an edit. This is actually the soul of Stack Overflow, put all together the knowledge of each other to produce quality content.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I would have but wasn't sure where to do so, as you didn't declare any variables, but the comment was made below your answer. :)